# Select Flowable emits too slowly in room

Tags: android, android-sqlite, rx-java2, android-room

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
class Item {
  @PrimaryKey
  var id=0
  @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
  var name=""
  @ColumnInfo(name = "thumbnail")
  var thumbnail=""
}

@RawQuery(observedEntities = [Item::class])
fun select(query:SupportSQLiteQuery):Flowable<List<Item>>
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [Item::class])
fun selectCount(query: SupportSQLiteQuery):Int

//query example
//select id,name,thumbnail from items 
//where (name like '%ruby%' and name like '%diamond%') and 
//(thumbnail like '%lion%' and thumbnail like '%tiger%')

DB.getInstance().Dao().select(query)
           .concatMapIterable { it }
            .concatMap {
                //blabla...
            }
```

The selectCount has a very short turnaround time, but with select, it emits almost one item per second. (Where the conditions of both functions are exactly the same)

Even when I access the same query directly with SQLiteOpenHelper, it is measured 10 times faster than using Room.

Is there anything I missed in improving speed? When I create a database instance, I use the following functions.

```
    fun getInstance(): DB {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(DB::class) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        getContext(),
                        DB::class.java, 
                        "test.db")
                        .build()
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE!!
    }
```